# Microsoft Graph PeopleManager.GetMyProperties does not refresh

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-graph-api

I just added two new properties for the users using sharepoint, and then I edited the values.The problem is that when entering to `<sharepointdomain>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getmyproperties` the new properties appear, but their values are empty. I changed the values from the sharepoint admin page, on `"users profiles" > "Manage Users Profiles"`. Why the changes are not being reflected on the rest api? Should I do something else?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out using the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are not calling Microsoft Graph, but the SharePoint endpoint. With Microsoft Graph you can get user profile information aggregated from Azure Active Directory, Exchange and SharePoint. However, It does not expose custom properties you add on the SharePoint profile service, but it does have a mechanism (going into preview very soon) for you to add open extensions and schematized extensions. For more info check this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2016/213